# add  scrollbar to JFreeChart 3DBarChart

Tags: java, scrollbar, jfreechart

Can I add a scroll bar to the JFreeChart that allows me **horizontally** move the bar ?

```
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D(
    title, 
    "X",
    "Y",
    dataset, 
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, 
    true, 
    false, 
    false
);
```

Because the dataset could be very long that there's not enough width to show the result...

Can I use JSlide on it? or other methods?

If possible, please show me some sample code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Yes you can, if you have access to the JFreeChart demo code just modify SlidingCategoryDatasetDemo2 and replace *createBarChart3D* with *createBarChart3D* and you will get this:

[image: 3d Scrolling Chart]

You will need to use a SlidingCategoryDataset.  You can find the source code and demos here [JFreeChart](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/)