# JFreeChart solution to draw a graph with a lot of data (>100) or (>1000)

Tags: java, swing, graph, jfreechart

I have a graph with a lot of data (>100) or (>1000). Here's how JFreeChart prints the graph now.

[image]

There are only 11 data points, and each person's name should appear on the x axis, but there are ellipses in place. Is there an ideal way to print large numbers of data like this?

```
public void barchartResults(ArrayList<Person> results, String testName) {
    int i;
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 20, 20));
    DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    String test = results.get(0).getTrait();

    for (i = 0; i < results.size(); i ++) { // Iterate until the end of the results array
        dataset.setValue(results.get(i).getScore(), results.get(i).getTrait(), results.get(i).getName());
    }

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D( testName + ": " + test,
            "Examinees", "Score", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false );

    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart, W, H, W, H, W, H, false, true, true, true, true, true); 
    chart.setBorderVisible(true);
    chartPanel.setSpaceBetweenGroupsOfBars(1);
    this.add(chartPanel);
    revalidate();
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- Invoke `setVerticalTickLabels()` on your domain axis, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513).
- Invoke `setCategoryLabelPositions()` with the desired angle, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12184526/230513) and [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BarRenderer.html).
- Use a `SlidingCategoryDataset`,as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10756404/230513) and in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).