# JFreeChart displaying three dots (...) in place of the values on the X axis

Tags: java, jfreechart, linechart

I am trying to plot a simple line chart and almost everything is fine, I am populating my dataset with a simple code like this:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
dataset.addValue(-10 , "S21" , "1000" );
dataset.addValue(-20 , "S21" , "1001" );
dataset.addValue(-25 , "S21" , "1002" );
dataset.addValue(-30 , "S21" , "1003" );
dataset.addValue(-25 , "S21" , "1004" );
...
```

then I create a line chart:

```
lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
    "S21",
    "Frequency (MHz)",
    "Value (db)",
    dataset,
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
    true,
    true,
    false);
```

and I have on the X axis the values 1000 1001 1002 ... etc. Anyway I noticed that, if I add some more points, jfreechart does not have enough space on the x axis and displays three dots (...) in the place of the values. This is pretty weird, I would like to have as many points as I like (e.g. 1000, to have a good
resolution) but the labels shown only for a subset of these points, so I do not run out od space:

E.g. points: 1000, 1001, 1002, ..., 2000 (1000 points)

Labels: 1000, 1100, 1200, ..., 1900, 2000 (10 labels)

Is it possible? I looked for a solution on the net, but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have to combine several approaches:

- Alter the `CategoryLabelPositions` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12178960/230513).

  ```
  CategoryAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
  domainAxis.setCategoryLabelPositions(
      CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(Math.PI / 2.0));
  ```
- Adjust the chart's size, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10274357/230513).

  ```
  ChartPanel piePanel = new ChartPanel(lineChart) {
      @Override
      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(640, 480);
      }
  };
  ```
- Optionally, depending on the number of categories, use a `SlidingCategoryDataset`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10754747/230513).
- Optionally, if the categories form a continuous domain, switch to an XY plot, e.g. `ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, with the line chart I can actually just to play with the size or rotate the label; but I can manage my case with XY line chart. It seem to work fine, thanks!